# Difference between "Todo lo demás" and "Todos los demás"

Tags: traducción

I am confused on the difference between "todo lo demás" and "todos los demás".

What is the literal difference between them and when one should be used instead of the other?

Comment: Yes, the question luislux found answers the question.  I don't have the rep to vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

The two phrases *todo lo demás* and *todo los demás* are the same except one is singular and the other is plural. Just take a look at the two pronouns "lo" and "los" to see the difference.

> todo lo demás --> *all the rest of **it** (lo)*
>
> todo los demás --> *all the rest of **them/those** (los)*

Examples:

> Todas **las demás** personas ya salieron. --> *All the rest of the people already left. **(plural, persons)***
>
> Yo puedo hacer todo **lo demás** del trabajo. --> *I can do all the rest of the work. **(singular, work)***
>
> Yo puedo lavar todos **los demás** trastes. --> *I can wash all the rest of the dishes. **(plural, dishes)***

Comment: Actually, *lo* is neuter, and therefore didn't refer to *trabajo* (the preposition *de* is key there). A more accurate, if loquacious, translation would actually be "I can do ask the rest of the stuff involved with the work". For the meaning you have, you'd need the rather uncommon (but grammatical) "yo puedo hacer todo **el** demás trabajo"

Comment: @guifa So it should actually read "Yo puedo hacer todo lo demás trabajo"?

Comment: "I can do all the rest of the stuff involved in the work" is "lo demás del trabajo", but "I can do all the rest of the work" would be "puedo hacer el demás trabajo".  (but *el resto de* is generally preferred these days over *el/la demás* for uncountables, although preference varies by individual nouns, time period, and probably geography too)